# Enclosing a password which contains special characters with curly braces does not work

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, data-migration, aws-dms

I am trying to create a data migration task on AWS in order to migrate data from one RDS instance to another. The instance password for the source endpoint contains special characters (+&;) and by enclosing it with curly braces (as it is suggested in the aws documentation) does not work. 
I successfully created the target endpoint.

Am I missing something?

**Update**

When creating an endpoint using aws cli the same issue occurs:

```
An error occurred (InvalidParameterValueException) when calling the CreateEndpoint operation: 
The parameter Password contains at least one unsupported characters from following list : ;+%
```

Is there really no way of doing this without changing the password?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There was really no way of doing this without changing the password.

Comment: Response from AWS Support in April 2020 about this: "This looks like a known issue with DMS, which is currently being worked on internally"

Comment: Just logged in to say this is still an issue. :/

Comment: Just confirmed this myself.  The documentation gives you the impression it is possible, but the underlying logic does not work for wrapping the complex password in curly braces.  Only solutions, as others have mentioned, is changing the password.  Which is really inconvenient for a production environment.

Answer (score 3):

Just encountered this issue today, while migrating an RDS Postgres DB using DMS. As per [official documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/dms/latest/userguide/CHAP_Endpoints.Creating.html), it's not supported in the endpoint password.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it is a known issue since 2017. [AWS Forums](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=266744)
Maybe create a new user and a password.

Answer (score 0):

I faced this same issue and there's no way of doing this without changing the password.

But what I did is I created a new DB root user just for migration purposes and gave that user a valid username and password.

Postgres Cmd:

```
CREATE USER roots WITH PASSWORD 'new-legal-password';

GRANT migration-root TO roots;
```

Created a new user called "migration-root" and gave that user root permission and it worked.